# Parse Log in With Twitter Initial Failure

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, parse-platform, authentication

Currently I have a Twitter login that authenticates the user just fine, receiving all the appropriate information for the user necessary for confirming a complete login.

I then am calling the `[PFTwitterUtils logInWithBlock:...]` method in order to authenticate the user through Parse and populate a new user in _User. 
(I am not using just this method to present the Twitter login dialog box as I could not get it to present itself).

Here is the strange part: 
On the first time I launch the app, I sign in with Twitter, and then call the logInWithBlock method and receive the following error:

```
Something went wrong: The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1012.)
```

The strange part is that this issue does not occur at all if I relaunch the app again. The only difference is that upon relaunch I believe the Twitter Account information that I had used before (via browser not accounts) is saved on the device. When I launch the app again, I have it set so that it reloads the previous session: this time the `[PFTwitterUtils logInWithBlock:...]` works like a charm, creates a new user, etc., without any issue.

NOTE: I have a valid URL saved as the Callback URL on my Twitter App's settings. Also, I hope it is clear that the setup was done correctly given that it works fine on second log in.

Here is the login code I am using:

```
// Login with Twitter through Parse
            [PFTwitterUtils logInWithBlock:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
                if (error != nil) {
                    // Something went wrong
                    NSLog(@"Something went wrong: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                    breakLogin = YES;
                    [self invalidateSignInTimer];
                    return;
                } 
                else if (user.isNew){
                    userObjectID = user.objectId;
                    [user saveInBackground];
                    NSLog(@"New User");
                }
                else if (!user.isNew) {
                    userObjectID = user.objectId;
                    [user saveInBackground];
                    NSLog(@"Returning User. Welcome Back!");
                }
            }];
```

I am running out of patience and ideas on why this is happening. If anyone has any ideas please let me know - thanks!

**UPDATE**:
I noticed that the reason this seems to be happening is such:
The first time i attempt to login there is no PFUser, whereas the second time there seems to be a saved `[PFUser currentUser]`, which allows the `[PFTwitterUtils...]` method to log in and create the new user.

Yet I am still not sure how to prevent the failure the first time without manually creating a new PFUser and then logging in with Twitter, then PFTwitterUtils...

**UPDATE 2**
I have resolved this issue with the answer I have provided below. I am leaving this up as I feel this is something that may help others out there in the future.

Comment: i would really appreciate if anyone could help. ive posted in 3 different "Parse" Q forums and not one person has gotten back to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after extraneous research, I seemed to have found a solution.

- First I made sure that all of my framework files (SKDs, headers, etc) were up to date by removing all of their references from both the project and the library linking.
- Second I made sure that all keys and secrets were remade and updated in my 
  `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {`
- Lastly I made double checked that I properly went through the set up for `Twitter authentication` through Parse's website.

**BUT** what I found to be the only solution rested in the **Callback URL**.

- When specifying the Callback URL in your Twitter Application under "Settings", I had to **uncheck** the Lock Callback URL option, despite the recommendation by Twitter. (seen below)
  [image]

I was a little unhappy that all of this trouble derived from something so mundane, however I was at least pleased that solution was in fact resolved without *too*  much trouble. Hopefully this answer helps someone out there struggling with a similar issue.